# php debugging with netbeans in ubuntu

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, netbeans-6.9

I cant make netbeans 6.9 work with xdebug. Strangely I tried `telnet`

```
nerkn@nerkn-laptop:~/www/nerkl$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
nerkn@nerkn-laptop:~/www/nerkl$ telnet bogaz  9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

also I cant find debugclient.

xdebug is working: I got logging and pretty error reporting.

What can I do?
I just want a basic step by step trace.

Answer (score 0):

> xdebug is working: I got logging and pretty error reporting.

You need to enable remote debugging.

Try this in `xdebug.ini`:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me; solved the debugging issue of netbeans it did not solved telnet "Connection refused" issue.

My solution:

In php.ini file (i.e. located in /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini); comment the option in [xdebug] section (usually the last section at the end of the file)

```
;xdebug.remote_autostart=on
```

then restart the apache service

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

try restarting the netbeans if this option was enabled and you disabled it.

@troelskn it not the xdebug.ini file; it is php.ini file.

---

---

Caution: If for now Xdebug only work with php 7.2. (Please only use uptil Xdebug 2.6, because later versions had some issues with debugging).
So if you had any other version installed like php 7.3 or 7.4 then oyu had to also install php 7.2 along side your current php version (mostly because now by default latest version is installed through apt). and then update in between alternatives.

---

---

To set PHP 7.0 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

To set PHP 7.2 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

To set PHP 7.3 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

To set PHP 7.4 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
```

Before we can configure Apache to use PHP 7.2, we need to disable the new (or old) version of PHP by typing

```
a2dismod php7.4
```

Now enable the newly installed PHP 7.2 version with the following command:

```
a2enmod php7.2
```

Restart the Apache web server for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: if you want the log file of xdebug add this in the php.ini; xdebug section. _xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log_ . Make sure that _xdebug directory and xdebug.log file are created_ in the specified location i.e. /var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log